# k-fold cross validation in quanteda

Tags: r, quanteda, k-fold

I've been using the quanteda SML workflow as described in the quanteda tutorial ([https://tutorials.quanteda.io/machine-learning/nb/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)) and found it extremely helpful to set up my own classification task. However, instead of the fixed held-out train/test sampling I would like to use a k-fold cross-validation. Could you point me towards the best way to implement it into the workflow? Is there an easy way to apply it in quanteda?

Many thanks

I tried to add a cross validation based on this example:
[https://rdrr.io/github/quanteda/quanteda.classifiers/man/crossval.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

```
require(quanteda)
require(quanteda.textmodels)
require(caret)


corp_movies <- data_corpus_moviereviews
summary(corp_movies, 5)
# generate 1500 numbers without replacement
set.seed(300)
id_train <- sample(1:2000, 1500, replace = FALSE)
head(id_train, 10)
# create docvar with ID
corp_movies$id_numeric <- 1:ndoc(corp_movies)

# tokenize texts
toks_movies <- tokens(corp_movies, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_number = TRUE) %>% 
  tokens_remove(pattern = stopwords("en")) %>% 
  tokens_wordstem()
dfmt_movie <- dfm(toks_movies)

# get training set
dfmat_training <- dfm_subset(dfmt_movie, id_numeric %in% id_train)

# get test set (documents not in id_train)
dfmat_test <- dfm_subset(dfmt_movie, !id_numeric %in% id_train)

tmod_nb <- textmodel_nb(dfmat_training, dfmat_training$sentiment)
summary(tmod_nb)

dfmat_matched <- dfm_match(dfmat_test, features = featnames(dfmat_training))

actual_class <- dfmat_matched$sentiment
predicted_class <- predict(tmod_nb, newdata = dfmat_matched)
tab_class <- table(actual_class, predicted_class)
tab_class

require(confusionMatrix)
confusionMatrix(tab_class, mode = "everything", positive = "pos")

#n-fold cross validation
require(crossval)
dfmat <- dfm(toks_movies)
tmod <- textmodel_nb(dfmat, y = data_corpus_moviereviews$sentiment)
crossval(tmod, k = 5, by_class = TRUE)
crossval(tmod, k = 5, by_class = FALSE)
crossval(tmod, k = 5, by_class = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)
```

but it returns "Error in group.samples(Y) : argument "Y" is missing, with no default"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should probably be a comment, but I cannot post them yet. I think your problem is caused by the usage of the `crossval()` function from the improper package. The link you shared suggests that you want to use it from the remote *quanteda/quanteda.classifiers* package, instead of *crossval*. The one you used presumably requires a different pipeline cause its definition is different. The used function requires additional X and Y arguments. Their lack is a reason for your error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, I do want to use the crossval function from the quanteda package. How I can make sure the function is used from the correct package?

Comment: First, you must install it with `require(remotes); remotes::install_github("quanteda/quanteda.classifiers")`. Then, load it with `library(quanteda.classifiers)`. To be absolutely sure it is a proper function type `quanteda.classifiers::crossval()` instead of plain `crossval()`.